# Is Either.right = Right and Either.Left=Left?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

At the next site:

https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/either.html

it is presented:

```
object EitherStyle {
  def parse(s: String): Either[Exception, Int] =
    if (s.matches("-?[0-9]+")) Either.right(s.toInt)
    else Either.left(new NumberFormatException(s"${s} is not a valid integer."))

  def reciprocal(i: Int): Either[Exception, Double] =
    if (i == 0) Either.left(new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot take reciprocal of 0."))
    else Either.right(1.0 / i)

  def stringify(d: Double): String = d.toString
}
```

Yet, I am getting the error:

```
[error] /application/learningSBT/hello-world/src/main/scala/Main.scala:16:39: value right is not a member of object scala.util.Either
[error]     if (s.matches("-?[0-9]+")) Either.right(s.toInt)
[error]                                       ^
[error] /application/learningSBT/hello-world/src/main/scala/Main.scala:17:17: value left is not a member of object scala.util.Either
[error]     else Either.left(new NumberFormatException(s"${s} is not a valid integer."))
[error]                 ^
[error] /application/learningSBT/hello-world/src/main/scala/Main.scala:21:14: value left is not a member of object scala.util.Either
[error]       Either.left(new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot take reciprocal of 0."))
[error]              ^
[error] /application/learningSBT/hello-world/src/main/scala/Main.scala:22:17: value right is not a member of object scala.util.Either
[error]     else Either.right(1.0 / i)
[error]                 ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Feb 12, 2020 10:25:02 AM
```

However, when I replaced Either.right with Right and Either.left with Left I got this code compiling:

```
object EitherStyle {
  def parse(s: String): Either[Exception, Int] =
    if (s.matches("-?[0-9]+")) Right(s.toInt)
    else Left(new NumberFormatException(s"${s} is not a valid integer."))

  def reciprocal(i: Int): Either[Exception, Double] =
    if (i == 0)
      Left(new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot take reciprocal of 0."))
    else Right(1.0 / i)

  def stringify(d: Double): String = d.toString
}
```

So, I wonder what makes this to happen.

Comment: So those are defined as **extension methods** [here](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/either.scala#L306) which you can bring into scope with `import cats.syntax.either._` - Its use is to improve type inference. since `Left(a)` returns a value of type `Left[A, Nothing]` whereas `Either.left(a)` returns a value of type `Either[A, Nothing]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension of cats to the standard `Either` object.

Import `cats.syntax.either._` for this to work.